# How to pass two variable in xhttp.open()? ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I m trying to pass two variable in xhttp.open() ,but i m getting Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list error

```
function showHint(str,Password)     
{  
  var xhttp;     
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();    
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()

 {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)

    {    
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;    
    }

 };    
  xhttp.open("GET","CheckLogin.php?fname=" +str+ "&password="+ Password, true);     
  xhttp.send();       
}
```

**error message:Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

i didnt had error while passing 1 variable .i get error only when trying to pass two variable in xhttp.open(). How to pass two variable in xhttp.open()?

Comment: i have fixed this , the problem was caused because i didnt passed proper variable to the function. the function is correct

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem i can see from your code is the

```
       xhttp.open("GET","CheckLogin.php?fname=" +Email+ "&password="+ Password, true);
```

Not sure where is the Email variable defined ?